i formated my timepicker to HH:mm but after giving the input in frontend , in backend its still taking 00:00 as input. what is the issue here?
i formated my timepicker to HH:mm but after giving the input in frontend , in backend its still taking 00:00 as input.
i am expecting it to take the proper input from the frontend and store it to the backend as it is.
the datepicker is working fine but the timepicker is the only thing that is causing the problem.

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider editing your question to include the relevant snippets of code, or even better, a minimal, reproducible example. You may also be interested in other Help Center articles, such as How do I ask a good question?

Component have a second parameter on onChange prop and it gives string format of selected time value.
